# How render custom error messages?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have a domain class :

```
package x

class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
        //other stuffs.
    static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
    email blank: false, email:true
    }
}
```

This is the class that I used for Spring security. In my `/register/index` page I need custom error messages, so I added these lines into `message.properties`:

```
x.User.username.unique=Username already exists. Please use other username.
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. I get only this error message : 
`Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null`

Even though I pass some value into my `username` column I still get this error message. I'm confused with it. How this `/register/index` comes from?

Where I need to change the error message?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you seeing that message? Can you add the relevant bit of your GSP or controller code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you've declarated the message code, it doesn't fallow the convention. Take a look [Validation and Internationalization](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html#validationAndInternationalization). Here you can find that the right way is
 `[Class Name].[Property Name].[Constraint Code]`
So your constraint should be

```
user.username.unique=Username already exists. Please use other username.
```